# How much time will no index no follow take for a node in drupal 7 to remove from google indexing

Tags: drupal-7, google-search, nofollow, noindex

I want to apply no index no follow to multiple nodes on my drupal 7 website. After applying no index no follow on those nodes, I deleted them.
Will no index no follow take effect or not, because nodes are deleted.
If deleting the nodes after appyling no index no follow is wrong way then should I unpublish those nodes ? Because I don't want to show those nodes on site as well as google search. Kindly suggest me better solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google crawls sites and indexing their pages time to time, depending on their rank. The better rank your website has the more often will it be crawled by google bot. And until next crawling it will display results from last one, of course. So Google will not be aware of any change you made after it's last crawling session.

However, you can ask Google to re-crawl your site. Check out instructions here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

and also on Google webmaster tools...